# modrewrite doesnt redirects silently

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^folder$ fd?id=190 [PT,L,QSA]
```

but it doesn't redirect correctly.

I get a `file not found` error.

If I write like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#RewriteMap keys txt:http://5000franquicias.com/API/frId/getlist   

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ fd?id=${keys:$1|0}

RewriteRule ^montelana$ fd?id=190 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

changing the flag PT to R=301 it works, but I want the redirecting to be made silently.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `PT`. Just use this:

```
RewriteRule ^folder$ fd?id=190 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: i was testing with PT, the only thing is actually working is when i use the R=301 flag. it returns a 404 not found whenever i use PT, r=200, or nc,l,qsa

Comment: Is ther some CMS/PHP framework running? Is there any oather code OR any other .htaccess there? What happens when you load `http://site.com/fd?id=190` ?

Comment: im using codeigniter, this is the only htacces file, if i go to  http://site.com/fd?id=190 it works good, and the redirect works fine only using RewriteRule ^montelana$ fd?id=190 [R=301,L,QSA]

Comment: CI has a front controller I believe that works on REQUEST_URI and because if silent redirection REQUEST_URI remains the original one and CI throws 404 because of that.

Comment: So you suggest me to investigate about that CI controller, or do yo know some way to avoid this and use modrewrite instead, thanks for taking your time helping, anubhava, sorry if i dont catch the idea, english isnt my native language

Comment: I would suggest looking into CI routing docs on how to work with mod rewrite silent rewrites.